# Copy part of array to Allocation

Tags: android, allocation, renderscript, android-renderscript

I want to process received data with renderscript, it contains 2 bytes header and few hundreds unaligned 3 bytes samples, which are represented in rs as vectors of 3 unsigned chars, so I need to copy samples only and strip the header.

Can I do it without copying part of array to the new array and filling `Allocation` from it?

Tried to use `Allocation.copy1DRangeFrom`, but now I'm assuming that `offset` parameter is an offset in the `Allocation` itself, not in the source array.

Answer (score 0):

Used NIO channel scattering read to separately read header and payload to different buffers and fill `Allocation` from buffer-backing array.